# Set hidden data on html stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to store some data on some html (the li elements) that I am adding to the DOM from an AJAX response. However it doesn't seem to be correct as I cant find it in Firebug or retrieve it.

I can't figure out how to successfully set the data without using the data attribute in the html which I don't want to do.

```
$.each(r.results, function(i, item) {
$tpl  = '<li>';
$tpl += '<figure>';
$tpl += '<img src="' + item.image + '" alt="' + item.name + '">';
$tpl += '</figure>';
$tpl += '</li>';
$($tpl).find('li').data('item-id', item.id);
$('#children ul').append($tpl);
});
```

Comment: You're not adding the data to `$tpl`, you're adding it to the disconnected nodes you created by parsing `$tpl`. Then you're parsing `$tpl` again when you append it to the DOM.

Comment: Why are you calling `find`? `$tpl` already has what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(r.results, function(i, item) {
    var $tpl  = '<li>';
    $tpl += '<figure>';
    $tpl += '<img src="' + item.image + '" alt="' + item.name + '">';
    $tpl += '</figure>';
    $tpl += '</li>';
    var $nodes = $($tpl);
    $nodes.data('item-id', item.id);
    $('#children ul').append($nodes);
});
```